# Unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable Ошибка с htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, apache2

ошибка:

```
[Sat Aug 25 21:41:51.724406 2018] [core:crit] [pid 32673] (13)Permission denied: [client 87.236.22.42:43006] AH00529: /home/admin/web/site.com/public_html/web/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/home/admin/web/site.com/public_html/web/' is executable
```

htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php



<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
</ifModule>

# сжатие text, html, javascript, css, xml:
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
</ifModule>

# кеш браузера
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On

#по умолчанию кеш в 5 секунд
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 days"

# Включаем кэширование изображений и флэш на месяц
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 4 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 30 days"
ExpiresByType image/svg "access plus 30 days"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 43829 minutes"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"

# Включаем кэширование css, javascript и текстовых файлоф на одну неделю
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"

# Включаем кэширование html и htm файлов на один день
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 43200 seconds"

# Включаем кэширование xml файлов на десять минут
ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"

# Нестандартные шрифты сайта
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Права на чтение то у него стоят? Если нет, то выполните:

```
chmod 644 /home/admin/web/site.com/public_html/web/.htaccess
```

Ну и чтоб папка была доступна для чтения и выполнения:

```
chmod 755 /home/admin/web/site.com/public_html/web/
```

Возможно с помощью `chown` команды ещё нужно овнера установить.

Посмотрите в `apache2.conf`, кто прописан в `User` и `Group` и сделайте его овнером папки:

```
chown -R User:Group /home/admin/web/site.com/public_html/web/
```

Где User и Group - это `User` и `Group`из `apache2.conf`.

Comment: Не выходит, все права поставлены

Comment: @DavidWeb а owner папки кто?

Comment: owner папки admin

Comment: @DavidWeb а апач под этим же юзером стучится? В `apache2.conf`, что прописано в `User` и `Group`?

Comment: `User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
#User www-data
#Group www-data`

Comment: @DavidWeb попробуйте тогда `chown -R www-data:www-data /home/admin/web/site.com/public_html/web/`

Comment: написал, не работает....

Comment: я все перекинул на admini, как в другой папке, которая была и сделал 700 разрешение. появилась ошибка - [Sun Aug 26 05:57:57.800347 2018] [php7:error] [pid 501] [client 87.236.22.42:44996] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/admin/web/jpaeigxifz.example.com/public_html/web/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://87.236.22.42/